# Custom Regex Query in an effiicient manner

Tags: python, regex, pandas, split, data-cleaning

So, I have a simple doubt but I am new to regex. I am working with a Pandas DataFrame. One of the columns contains the names. However, some names are written like "John Doe" but some are written like "John.Doe" and I need to write all of them like "John Doe". I need to run this on the whole dataframe. What is the regex query to fix this and in an efficient manner. Col Name = 'Customer_Name'. Let me know if more details are needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running this to replace all . with space, if that is your only condition:

```
df['Customer_Name'] = df['Customer_Name'].str.replace('.', ' ')
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to use `apply` function from pandas that applies a function to all the values on column. You do not need regex for this but below is an example that has both

```
import pandas as pd
import re

# Read CSV File
df = pd.read_csv(<PATH TO CSV FILE>)

# Apply Function to Column
df['NewCustomerName'] = df['Customer_Name'].apply(format_name)

# Function that does replacement
def format_name(val):
  return val.replace('.', ' ')
  # return re.sub('\.', ' ', val) # If you would like to use regex
```